# Advantages of Open ID connect

Tags: facebook, oauth, openid

I have been following OAuth 2.0, Open ID and now Open ID connect. They say that Open ID connect has Identity in addition to OAuth. From this, can it be inferred that it can be used for both authentication and authorization? Say I have to Integrate certain services of Youtube or Facebook into my web application, I currently use just OAuth. Instead, can I switch to Open ID connect and do the same things?

Answer (score 1):

Open ID Connect is just another layer on top of OAuth. You'll still use OAuth for authorization, but now you can also perform authentication with it. It doesn't make sense to "switch to Open ID Connect", because Open ID Connect uses OAuth.

Some references:

- [Difference Between OAUTH, OpenID and OPENID Connect in very simple term?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/44611/difference-between-oauth-openid-and-openid-connect-in-very-simple-term/)
- [Why use OpenID Connect instead of plain OAuth?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37818/why-use-openid-connect-instead-of-plain-oauth)
- [Open ID Connect specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html)